# How to create a report for an epic - issues created, added, removed, and closed as done?

Tags: jira, metrics, epics

I am trying to create a report (either Jira or eazyBI) that shows entries within an epic or initiative on a monthly basis - the entries newly created, removed, and closed as done.

We have 2 initiatives set for a release. They each have several epics under them. But as we have had to do "ruthless prioritization", some entire epics or issues within epics have been moved out from under these 2 initiatives. In eazyBI, we have created a monthly report showing issues created and closed, but the data is skewed by the entries that are moved. I am looking to add a third data point for each month, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I cannot find a resolution in Jira or eazyBI, the 2 main tools we use. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you have a JIRA admin? If there's no built-in reporting for this, you might need to do it via API.

Comment: Thank you, Todd. I do have a Jira admin - could you suggest what he could do? We are both posting in threads like this to find a solution.

Comment: See https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/ for documentation. API engineering is out of scope for PMSE.